# ing-clause grammar question

Tags: relative-clauses, present-participles

Anyone know why **providing** was used here? Is using **which provides** here correct?

> We have a weekly Western Canada newsletter written by our B.C. and Alberta bureau chiefs, **providing** a comprehensive package of the news you need to know about the region and its place in the issues facing Canada.

Comment: Because otherwise it would have to be: and it provides etc. Not as pretty.

Answer (score 3):

It is a perfectly normal participial clause post-modifying the noun phrase *a weekly Western Canada newsletter written by our B.C. and Alberta bureau chiefs*.

Just like *I saw Tom **waiting for a bus***.

You can usually replace such clauses by relative clauses, so your *which provides* would be good as well.